# Wordpress perma links

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Ok i made plugin for contact form, thing is i have redirection when form is submited to success page

```
$location = home_url().'/potvrda-prijave/';
wp_safe_redirect($location);
exit();
```

thing is when someone change permalinks structure i will get 404, does anybody knows how to grab permalinks change and change my redirection link? something like this

```
$location = home_url().'/potvrda-prijave/';
```

to

```
 $location = home_url().'id=21';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the page ID, you can simply use [get_permalink()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink):

```
$location = get_permalink( 21 );
```

EDIT: It looks like you don't actually know the ID...In that case, if you know the title, you can use:

```
$location = get_permalink( get_page_by_title( 'Your Page Title' ) );
```

However, if you're using [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to create the post in the first place, that function returns the page ID of the added post. So:

```
$added_post = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
$location = get_permalink( $added_post );
```

Comment: explain more i am creating page with my plugin how, can i know under wich id will be saved

Comment: Your question was unclear. Since you are creating the page with your plugin, you should at least know the page title. You can then use the second method I have listed.